# How to choose coefficients to have 50% True and 50% False in the Dummy variable in R?

Tags: r, simulation

Below you see my assignment. I can not perform **e**.

**a**.  Choose a sample size of nObs for your simulations (e.g. 100 observations).

```
n<-100
```

**b**.  Set the initial state of your statistical software’s pseudo-random-number generator to a specific value in order to make your simulation results reproducible.

```
set.seed(1111)
```

**c**.  Create a data set with two potentially correlated random variables x and z.

```
library(faux)
dat <- rnorm_multi(n,
                   mu = c(10000, 50000),
                   sd = c(1000, 5000),
                   r = c(0.35),
                   varnames = c("x", "z"),
                   empirical = FALSE)
```

**d**.  Add two potentially correlated random error terms e1 and e2 to your data set.

```
dat_error<-rnorm_multi(n,
                       mu = c(0, 0),
                       sd = c(1, 1),
                       r = c(0.35),
                       varnames = c("e1", "e2"),
                       empirical = FALSE)

all_dat<-cbind(dat, dat_error)
```

**e**.  Add a treatment dummy variable to your data set that you calculate by
D = I(α0 + α1 x + α2 z + e1 > 0), (1)
where you choose values for α0, α1, and α2 so that the proportion of ‘treated’ observations is around 50% and I(·) is an indicator function that returns one  if the expression in parenthesis in true and a zero if the expression in parenthesis is false.

```
a0<-10
a1<--10
a2<--7

D<- I(a0 + a1*all_dat$x + a2*all_dat$z + all_dat$e1 > 0)

D[1:5]
sum(D)
```

If I run **e**, R returns only false.
If you know how to solve this problem please help me:)

Comment: The means of your `x` and `z` variables are both 10 times greater than their std deviations.  Therefore, they are almost certainly positive(and large).  Therefore the `average` value that your 'I' function is comparing to zero is -10 - 10* (something large and positive) -7 *(something large and positive) = something negative.  As your question says, you need to "Choose values for a0, a1 and a2...".  Your current values are inappropriate.

Comment: @Limey How should I choose a0,a1,a2? In order to receive 50% D True and 50% D False.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a homework service. You know the average values of x and y. So experiment to find values of a0, a1 and a2 that give a value on the LHS of the inequality that give a value of about zero.